# PS1: How to exclude words from line

Tags: powershell

In this case, how can I exclude the file path part of this line?

Link:

```
www.website.com/downloads/file.exe
```

Can be .exe, .zip, etc.

Output Goal:

```
file.exe
```

Also want to use it as so:

```
$x = file.exe

$path = C:\Users\Downloads\$x
```

How can this be pulled of using powershell?

Comment: It might help you to read [ask].

Comment: Probably the most convenient way here is to use .Net [System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path) class for this:
`$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('www.website.com/downloads/file.exe')  # --> file.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split-path` cmdlet with the parameter `-leaf`:

```
'www.website.com/downloads/file.exe' | Split-Path -leaf
```

Will have an output of `file.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to search a bit more before asking.
I did easily find the solution online in 5 minutes.

```
$link = 'www.website.com/downloads/file.exe'

$lastSlashPos = $link.LastIndexOf('/')
$fileNameWithExtension = $link.Substring($lastSlashPos+1)
```

Articles:

- [LastIndexOf](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-windows-powershell/9781787126305/7c8b356e-1d56-4262-92f4-53a14efa7f7e.xhtml)
- [Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203730/cut-off-text-in-string-after-before-separator-in-powershell)